# react native app not running on physical iOS device from MacOS bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, react-native, react-native-ios

Following the react-native documentation installed all the node dependencies and pods
the simulator launches when the react-native run-iOS command is used and the app won't launch!
while trying to launch the app on a physical device it shows an error!

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWX0.png)

`Bundle identifier is missing.
AwesomeProject doesn't have a bundle identifier. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor.`

Comment: Error is really clear, you must add a `bundle identifier` to your project. To run on a physical device you must provide a `bundle identifier` and have a provisioning profile

Comment: Yeah, I also tried adding bundle identifier
Do we need to be an apple developer for having a provisioning id??

Comment: You can try to run with a fake bundle id but if it doesn’t work it means you have to provide a provisioning profile and thus have an Apple developer account